# How to show qty product sold in catalog/product/list.phtml in mageto 2

Tags: magento2

How to show qty product sold in catalog/product/list.phtml in mageto 2?
Example like link the screenshot below:
http://prntscr.com/rapduu
Anyone hepl me?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Create a function in Block and add below code in that.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
class SoldItems extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
  protected $_soldCollection
  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context, 
    \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Sold\Collection $soldCollection,
     array $data = []) {
     $this->_soldCollection = $soldCollection;
      parent::__construct($context, $data);
   }
 /*
   returns sold qty by using sku
 */
  public function getSoldQty($sku){
     $soldProduct = $this->_soldCollection->addOrderedQty()->addAttributeToFilter('sku', 
     $sku)->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc')->getFirstItem(); 
     $soldQty = $soldProduct ->getOrderedQty();
     return $soldQty;
  }
}
```

The above function returns the sold Qty by taking sku as parameter.

call this block function in your list.phtml by passing sku of the product as a parameter.

**Hope this may help you!!**

Comment: Thank for support, but how to can simple add in file list.phtml?

Comment: @TienNguyen, you will have product sku, inside for each call this function.

Comment: Hi jafar pinjar, no my mean how to can get qty product sold in file list.phtml without build function in Block. Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure how to get directly in list page, but if you use it like above, you will he the result.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much!